# Move an item within a DynamoDB list

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a list in a DynamoDB table and would like to move items to different positions in the same list, is there a way to do this in a single update?

At the moment, I'm looking at having to read the list, modify it, then write it back again, but would prefer doing it all in a single update, is there a way to do this?

**Edit to add example**

So here's some noddy data that shows what I'd like to do:

If the data started like this:

`Item: { COLUMN: [ "Element_0", "Element_1", "Element_2", "Element_3" ] }`

Then I'd give it `from` and `to` indices and it would move the element. So for example if I gave it a `from` index of 0 and `to` index of 2 the data should end up like this:

`Item: { COLUMN: [ "Element_1", "Element_2", "Element_0", "Element_3" ] }`

Comment: I assume you mean a list within a single item. Can you give example data? What does the item in the table look like? What information do you have when doing the update? What is the desired final state?

Comment: Yes that's right, all the information to locate the list is available and it's just one list within a single item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with an [Update Expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html), but it's a little tricky, since you don't have the data.

Basically, you have to create a dynamic update statement that sets every value you want to move. Something like this works:

```
aws dynamodb update-item --table-name test --key '{"pk":{"S":"1"}}' --update-expression "SET #list[1] = #list[2], #list[2] = #list[1]" --region us-west-2 --profile jw-test --expression-attribute-names '{"#list": "list"}'
```

I created a table with a key of `pk`, with a value of `1`. The `list` before the update was like this:

```json
[
'one',
'two',
'three',
'four'
]
```

After the update it looks like this:

```json
[
'one',
'three',
'two',
'four'
]
```

Comment: Hmmm interesting, looks like it can handle swaps without needing temp objects which is what I was worried about, will give it a whirl thanks!

Comment: What's the reason for using `--expression-attribute-names` in this query to map `list` to the same name? Does `"SET list[1] = list[2], list[2] = list[1]"` not work and why not?

Comment: I prefer to use the expression attribute names to avoid reserved words. I don’t want to have to check if list is a reserved word.

Answer (score -1):

Default answer if this isn't possible in a single update.

Read out the list, modify it, then write it back. It's not elegant, but it works and isn't *that* ugly either.

It's not atomic though so any answer that can do it in a single update will get the check mark.